# python writing csv Django for loop

Tags: python, django, csv, file-io

I'm a bit stuck with writing a csv file using the python csv library. I'm using Django to get the information into objects out of a database.

What I have now, works but is not yet complete:

```
writer.writerow([Itag.Gen_ID if Itag else '',
     Itag.Solyc if Itag else '',
     Itag.GO_number if Itag else '',
     Itag.GO_def if Itag else '',
     Itag.Itag_description if Itag else '',
     Itag.IPR_Number if Itag else '',
     Itag.IPR_Description if Itag else '',
     Itag.Trivial_name if Itag else '',
     Loci.Locus_symbol if Loci else '',
     Loci.Locus_name if Loci else '',])
```

This writes away the object information into a CSV file if there is a object present.
Now in the next part I Have a Object called `Blast`,
`Blast` Has a couple of properties:
`Blast.name, Blast.hit, Blast.score`
The object `Itag` has a one on one relation with `Loci` that's why it all fits nicely in a row.

Now the `Blast` object has a many on one relation with `Itag`and `Loci`
so 5 `Blast` hits can have a relation with 1 `Itag and Loci` Hit.

Now how do I write all the 5 `Blast` object properties to the same row in the CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's untidy and but the most obvious solution is to append the hits to the line:

```
<all that other stuff>, first_blast_name, first_blast_hit, first_blast_score, second_blast_name, second...<and so on>
```

Personally I'd rarely, if ever, do it this way. I'd rather have one csv file for `loci` and another for `blast`.

Comment: the problem is here is that I never know how many Blast hits there are..  so how do you suggest appending that to the row?

Comment: you know that past the other stuff there are only blast hits, so just keep appending them. Or keep a separate blasts file.  What's the problem here?

Comment: Yes, after the other stuff there are only blast hits. separate blast file is possible but not a good solution for my problem.

How do I append them then? If I don't know how many blast hits I'll get? another `writer.writerow()` is not going to work because that creates a new line. how do I append all the object properties to that line then?

Comment: You can prepare the list before reaching writerow.  It doesn't need to be done right there and then.  You can even append lists to a list in a loop, thus making really long arbitrary length lists/rows.

Comment: Can you show how to do it like that then? because I tried that but the writer messes it up, puts all the information in one column.
can you write a piece of example code for me?

Comment: Approach it methodically; breaking the puzzle up into small pieces and confirming each piece works before moving on the next, taking care not to turn into a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

Comment: I think I found it! It's a bit dirty code. and now I have to figure out how I'm going to do the file header, but writing to a list works now..

Comment: And, I'll try to not turn into a help vampire.. But as just a young student I'm still learning. and yes.. I still make stupid mistakes like forgetting to remove the "[]" when writing a list instead of objects..